# SQL Server using where column_name like N'%Ө%'

Tags: sql-server-2008, unicode

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column_name LIKE N'%Ө%'
```

When I use this query, it returns all rows of the table.

It works like :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column_name LIKE '%%'
```

I also tried :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column_name LIKE N'%ӨTӨEӨSӨTӨ%'
```

and it works like :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column_name LIKE '%TEST%'
```

Comment: use appropriate collation

Comment: currently using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, other unicode characters are working properly, except for this one.

Answer (score 0):

use collation **Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS**, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column_name LIKE N'%Ө%' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS
OR column_name LIKE N'%ӨTӨEӨSӨTӨ%' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS
```

Comment: It would be clearer if you can elaborate further rather than just `use Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS`.

Comment: added example. @BernardL